# Can we make an array in which first two elements are int type and third element is itself an array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, constructor

I am trying to solve a practice problem which is:

> Assume below basic skeleton of Student and GradeBook class:
>
> ```
> public class GradeBook {
>    private String courseName;
>    private Student[] students;
> // ... other methods .... 
> }
> public class Student{
>    private int id;
>    private String name;
>    int marks[];   // marks in different tests
> }
> ```
>
> Encapsulate fields and defined needed constructors. Then, make a GradeBook object and fully initialize it based on user input. Get number of students from user input. As number of tests each student given may be different, so your program shall take number of tests and marks in each test, form user input too. You can also generate and use random number to quickly initialize whole data, instead of getting from user, but choose decent ranges e.g. maximum marks 100, maximum students 50 and maximum number of test each student may give shall be less or equal to 10. After fully initializing the GradeBook object, print following information:
> Which student given maximum number of test, print student id
> Who got maximum average marks, print student id.
> Average marks of the class
> Average marks of each student in the class
> Minimum marks of each student, print marks and student id
> Maximum marks of each student,  print marks and student id
> Average, minimum and maximum marks of the student (get student from user)
> Some methods shall be written in Student class and some inside the GradeBook class, decide the best place for a method based on what it does. Perform all listed tasks in different methods and call those methods from the main method in GradeBook test class.

My code (incomplete):

Main class

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();

        System.out.println("Enter No. of Students: ");

        Student[] students = new Student[sc.nextInt()];

        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("----- (STUDENT - %d) -----\n", i+1);

            System.out.println("No. of Tests given: ");
            int[] marks = new int[sc.nextInt()];

            System.out.println("Enter ID and Name: ");
            students[i] = new Student(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine(), marks);
    }
}
```

I cannot understand how I can make array of students with id, name and array of marks in it as its elements.

Comment: Sounds like you're lacking [a fundamental understanding of what Objects are](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm). You wouldn't have an Array with separate value types. You'd have an Array of `Student` objects that you [instantiate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) and add to the array.

Comment: @user15793316 I would not recommend telling a new programmer about that. It will give them bad habits and/or confuse them since they will need to perform casting to utilize anything they put into such an Array.

Comment: @user15793316 Hard to say. Certainly at least equally as bad as putting the bad idea in their head to begin with when they lack understanding of why it's bad. Neither are ideal. Guess I tend to favor letting people discover bad ideas with the hope they've learned enough at that point to recognize it as such instead of giving them the bad idea in the first place when they don't have enough experience to understand why it's a bad idea and thus are likely to ignore the warning since it accomplishes what they want to do.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Instead you should define an array (or list) of students where each item holds the students data.